# Weighted uniform convergence of Taylor series of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

> Is the limit 
>   $$
> e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n\to e^{-2x}  \quad \text{as } \ N\to\infty \tag1
> $$
>   uniform on $[0,+\infty)$?

Numerically this appears to be true: see the difference of two sides in (1)  for $N=10$ and $N=100$ plotted  below. But the convergence is very slow (<strike>logarithmic</strike>  error $\approx N^{-1/2}$ as shown by Antonio Vargas in his answer). In particular, putting $e^{-0.9x}$ and $e^{-1.9x}$ in (1) clearly makes convergence non-uniform.

One difficulty here is that the Taylor remainder formula is effective only up to $x\approx N/e$, and the maximum of the difference is at $x\approx N$.

[image: N=10]

[image]

The question is inspired by an attempt to find an alternative proof of [$\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-e^{-x}p|<\epsilon\forall x\in[0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/386807/).

Comment: I have no time to give a full answer at this moment, but I think [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/225063/46120), in particular my answer there and Stirling's formula are enough to prove your statement.

Comment: @Landscape Julien says my idea might be what you had in mind. Care to take a look?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: What I intended to say is as follows. For $r_n(x)=e^{-x}-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{k!}$ with $x>0$, from $r_{n-1}(x)\cdot r_n(x)<0$ we know that $|r_{n-1}(x)|<|r_{n-1}(x)-r_n(x)|=\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then it suffices to estimate $f_n(x)=e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. $f_n'(x)=0\iff x=n$, so $0<f_n(x)\le f_n(n)$, and the conclusion follows from Stirling's lemma. However, it turns out that $|r_{n-1}(x)|<\frac{x^n}{n!}$ follows from Taylor's expansion of $e^{-x}$ at $x=0$ with  Lagrange form of the remainder immediately, so  the observation $r_{n-1}(x)\cdot r_n(x)<0$ is not necessary.

Comment: @Landscape I will try to make my answer more meaningful by imitating your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: You are welcome. I will be glad to see your updated answer.

Comment: @Landscape I think it is nonsensical to try to obtain a simpler argument than the one above, thus I will add that to my answer and properly attribute you for it. If you'd like to answer on your own, I can just delete it and worry about what this question [gave rise to](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443825/let-x-n-be-the-unique-root-of-delta-f-nx-0-then-delta-x-n-to-1).

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Please feel free to edit your answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits should go to [Landscape](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/46120/landscape).

Define $$r_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Note that by Taylor's theorem with [Lagrange's form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) we can write $$r_n(x)=(-1)^{n+1}e^{-x'}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

where $x'$ is positive. It follows $$e^{-x}|r_n(x)|\leq e^{-x}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Easy verification shows the last function has absolute maximum at $x=n+1$. But $$\frac{1}{{(n + 1)!}}{\left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{e}} \right)^{n + 1}} \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi \left( {n + 1} \right)} }}$$ by Stirling, so convergence is indeed uniform. $\quad \Box$

Comment: @40votes I am trying to see if it is possible to estimate the roots of $f_n^{\prime}$ to see where the maxima lies.

Comment: The fact that that the sign of the remainder alternates is not immediate, though. I think your approach is what Landscape is suggesting in his comment.

Comment: @julien Using landscape's idea and $r_{n+1}^\prime=-r_n$, it is not too hard. =)

Comment: Just saying it is not obvious when you read it first.

Comment: @julien True. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Downvote? Meh...

Comment: It seems that you need some kind of uniformity in the convergence of your first displayed equation.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: No, I mean the family converges to $1$ uniformly in $x$ as $n\to\infty$, or whatever can guarantee that when you replace $r_n(x)$ with the monomial, you will still be able to prove the uniform convergence of the original sequence.

Comment: @Landscape Ah, I see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9652/discussion-between-peter-tamaroff-and-landscape)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, this was a fun problem.

From the integral representation

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^\infty (x+t)^n e^{-t} \,dt  \tag1
$$

we can derive the expression

$$
e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} = e^{-2x} - \frac{e^{-2x} (-x)^{n+1}}{n!} \int_0^1 t^n e^{xt}\,dt. \tag2
$$

Now

$$
\int_0^1 t^n e^{xt}\,dt \leq e^x \int_0^1 t^n\,dt = \frac{e^x}{n+1}, \tag3
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{e^{-2x} (-x)^{n+1}}{n!} \int_0^1 t^n e^{xt}\,dt\right| &\leq \frac{e^{-x} x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \\
&\leq \frac{e^{-n-1} (n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
\end{align} \tag4
$$

by Stirling's formula.

---

Added by *40 votes* for those interested in the derivation of (2) from (1): 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (t-x)^n e^{-t} \,dt  +
\frac{1}{n!} \int_x^\infty (t-x)^n e^{-t} \,dt \tag{A}
$$
Substitute $u=t-x$ in the second integral on the right of (A): 
$$\frac{1}{n!}\int_x^\infty (t-x)^n e^{-t} \,dt
=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u-x} \,dt = e^{-x}
 \tag{B}$$
Substitute $u=1-t/x$ in the first integral on the right of (A), noting that $(t-x)^n=(-x)^n u^n$ and $dt=(-x)du$: 
$$\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (-x+t)^n e^{-t} \,dt 
= \frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{n!} \int_0^1 u^n e^{xu-x} \,du = \frac{e^{-x}(-x)^{n+1}}{n!} \int_0^1 u^n e^{xu} \,du \tag{C}
$$
Adding (B) and (C), identity (2) follows.

Comment: Interestingly, your integral representation shows that we can estimate the remainder by $\frac{e^{-x}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ just as if we had said that $\Big|\sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\Big|\leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ by invoking Leibniz criterion (which unfortunately requires $n>x$ here, whence can't be uniform). +1.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Having spent several minutes figuring out the transition (1)->(2), I added it in case others are doing the same.

Comment: @40votes Thank you :).  Sometimes I have a habit of leaving maybe a bit too much to the reader.

Comment: Moved the checkmark because Landscape and Peter came up with an embarrassingly simple answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide another solution which is a mixture of Antonio's and Landscape's. One can also write $$\left|r_n(x)\right|=\int_0^x {e^{-t}}\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt$$

by virtue of Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder. But then again $$\left| {{r_n}(x)} \right| \leqslant \int_0^x {\frac{{{{(x - t)}^n}}}{{n!}}dt}  = \int_0^x {\frac{{{u^n}}}{{n!}}du}  = \frac{x^{n + 1}}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}$$

and Strling does the job.

Comment: Next step: try to find a simpler solution of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/386807/85506) than the one linked in comments there...

Comment: @40votes Heh, that is interesting.

Comment: @40votes Mind dropping to chat?