# Find a number from which a series is bounded

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Find a number N s.t $\forall x>0 $ and $ n\ge N: |\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {(-1)^kx^k}{k!}|<2$

**Thoughts**
We used the remainder of the taylor series of $e^{-x}$, after some bounding we got stuck. Would love someone's help finishing up.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you finishing up, such an $N$ does not exist. $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^kx^k}{k!}$$ is, for $n \geqslant 1$, a non-constant polynomial, and thus unbounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Your problem currently asks for *single* value of $N$ which would work for all $x$ at the same time (i.e. $(\exists N)(\forall x)(\forall n\geq N)$). As Daniel pointed out, this is impossible. However, if you asked for $N$ after being given $x$, the problem would become more interesting (i.e. $(\forall x)(\exists N)(\forall n\geq N)$)...

Comment: I think maybe that's what the writer of this question meant

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Fischer said, it is impossible to choose $N$ independently of $x$. But after $x>0$ is fixed, we can find $N$ as follows: since $|e^{-x}|<1$, it suffices to bound the remainder   $r_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^kx^k}{k!}$ by $1$. The [Lagrange form of remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/443579/) yields $$ |r_n(x)|\leq  \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
According to [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), 
$$(n+1)!\ge \sqrt{2\pi}(n+1)^{n+3/2}e^{-n-1}$$
Thus, $$ |r_n(x)|\leq  \left(\frac{ ex }{ n+1}\right)^{n+1} $$
and choosing $N=\lfloor ex\rfloor$ does the job.